# Catch closure or invalidation file-HANDLE

Tags: c++, winapi, handle

I have some problems with printing messages into console via `std::wcout`. Before use `FreeConsole` and `AttachConsole` everything works fine. But, after that printing does not work. I dig deeper into printing implementation, and it use `WriteConsoleW((HANDLE) _confh, ...)` where `_confh` is singleton:

```
_confh = (intptr_t) CreateFileW(
  L"CONOUT$",
  GENERIC_WRITE,
  FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
  NULL,
  OPEN_EXISTING,
  0,
  NULL
);
```

`WriteConsoleW` fails with `LastErrorCode = ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`.
I know `_confh` value, and I want to find out when and why this handle becomes invalid. I put breakpoint into `CloseHandle()` method, but it is not caused.

The question is, how `HANDLE` can become invalid without closure? Is it possible to determine when `HANDLE` becomes invalid?

Comment: The handle might be valid but the object behind it has gone. That happened when you freed the console.

Comment: Note that this behaviour will vary depending on the version of Windows.  Anyways, you'll need to open a new console handle and associate it with the C++ standard output, just as you would if the application had been launched without a console.  I believe a search of Stack Overflow should turn up a solution.

Comment: @David Heffernan, I thought `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE` means exactly `HANDLE` is invalid, not related object. Thanks, I realize my mistake.